# Weird behavior in anonymous inner class using vanilla GWT

Tags: gwt

```
public class TestComposite extends Composite{
    private String str = "hello";

    public TestComposite() {
        Keymaster.get().bindShortcuts("alt+up", new Keymaster.KeymasterHandler() {
            @Override
            public void process(String shortcut) {
                if (isAttached()) {
                    GWT.log("do the job");//why enter here even if TextComposite is detached
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The above class is a GWT composite, what makes me confused is, why the line run even if TextComposite is detached?(see code)

KeyMaster is my wrapper around mousetrap.js, its keyboard binding is global, which mean, even if the TestComposite is detached, the `process()` method is still executed when I press a shortcut. So I use `isAttached()` to prevent it run when the composite is not <s>shown</s> in DOM, however it DID run and `isAttached()` return true, could anybody explain this?

Answer (score 0):

isAttached != isVisible. The javadoc for isAttached says

```
'Determines whether this widget is currently attached to the browser's 
 document (i.e., there is an unbroken chain of widgets between this widget 
 and the underlying browser document).'
```

Try with

```
if(isVisible()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: TestComposite is not in DOM, rather than invisible, I edit my post, Thanks anyway.